# Replacing characters, Backslashes and Double quotes note fully working

Tags: javascript, json, csv, escaping

I am trying to replace one backslash `\` with two `\\` however my double quotes is not working..

```
var json = {
    "DateToday": "2021-08-11",
    "MetaData": [
        {
            "id": "222",            
            "nameUsed": " \"data\" somemorefillerdata» - somemorefillerdata «somemorefillerdata»",
            "type": "movies"
        }
    ]
}

let newJson = JSON.stringify(json)
let newnewJson = newJson.replace(/\\"/g, "\\\\");
let newnewnewJson = JSON.parse(newnewJson)
console.log(newnewnewJson)
```

So this kind of works however my output does not include the quotes it looks like this -

```
{
  DateToday: '2021-08-11',
  MetaData: [
    {
      id: '222',
      nameUsed: ' \\data\\ somemorefillerdata» - somemorefillerdata «somemorefillerdata»',
      type: 'movies'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use backticks `` for string consisting of multiple quotes and variables. It'll make it more readable as well.

Comment: You have no quote in the replacement string. It should be `'\\\\"'`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but I am now getting a Syntax error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 66

{"DateToday":"2021-08-11","MetaData":[{"id":"222","nameUsed":" \\"data\\" 
                                                                                                             

Under the D in data

Comment: Why are you making changes to JSON? It should already be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add one more `\` then replace this line:

```
let newnewJson = newJson.replace(/\\"/g, `\\\\\\\\`);
```

As I understand from the question, you try to get this output:

```
" \\data\\ somemorefillerdata» - somemorefillerdata «somemorefillerdata»"
```

before it was:

```
" \data\ somemorefillerdata» - somemorefillerdata «somemorefillerdata»"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the use for replacing `\` with `\\`. Here the starting point is a object literal. It is then stringifyed, returning the expected result. And then parsed into an object again, returning the expected result.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  DateToday: "2021-08-11",
  MetaData: [{
    id: 222,
    nameUsed: " \"data\" somemorefillerdata» - somemorefillerdata «somemorefillerdata»",
    type: "movies"
  }]
};

let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
console.log(jsonStr);

let newJsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr)
console.log(newJsonObj.MetaData[0].nameUsed)
```